# Change color of checkbox button

Tags: css, css-selectors, google-app-maker

I have a changed the appearance of a checkbox from "Regular" to "Switch" in Google App Maker. I would now like to change the appearance of the knob when the it is pushed from blue to green. How can I do that? The following CSS style is not working:

```
.app-Checkbox-Input:checked, {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I would also like to put the label on the left side of the checkbox, if possible.

Comment: you have a comma after checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize the switch we need to customize the knob itself and the oval area behind it (**2 things**), and once we override styles for checked state we also need to redefine styles for its unchecked state (**2 states**). What gives us **2x2=4** custom styles. We also have multiple ways how to implement styles: override them individually for every widget, customize built-it AM style, implement all-new style from scratch or extend AM built in style using CSS class. I will not cover all these options in this answer this time, but let's start at least with something:

Styles for **individual widget**:

```
/* Styles for Checkbox widget on the page NewPage with name
   GreenSwitch */

/* Recolor knob's checked state */
.app-NewPage-GreenSwitch-Label::after {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Recolor knob's unckecked state */
.app-NewPage-GreenSwitch>.app-NewPage-GreenSwitch-Input:checked+.app-NewPage-GreenSwitch-Label::after {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Recolor back oval checked state */
.app-NewPage-GreenSwitch-Input {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.4);
}

/* Recolor back oval unchecked state */
.app-NewPage-GreenSwitch-Input:checked {
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Recolor **all checkboxes** with Switch style variant

```
.app-Checkbox--Switch>.app-Checkbox-Label::after {
  background-color: green;
}

.app-Checkbox--Switch>.app-Checkbox-Input:checked+.app-Checkbox-Label::after {
  background-color: red;
}

.app-Checkbox--Switch>.app-Checkbox-Input {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.4);
}

.app-Checkbox--Switch>.app-Checkbox-Input:checked {
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

**Result**

[image: Recolored switch]

Comment: Thank you very much, Pavel. This is most helpful.